# Laravel jQuery line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, laravel-5.1

I have 4 different models, and of course 4 different database tables. I need to make a line chart, that shows, how many new records, of each table have been made on a particular day. The chart must show records of current month, but only show the days, on which at least one record has been created. I currently have such chart made with jQuery, but I don't know, how to make an array, to pass to the chart. The array should look like this (except, that I have 4 types of records, so that would be (a, b, c, d):

```
data: [
                    { date: '07-31-2015', a: 6, b: 90 },
                    { date: '08-01-2015', a: 0, b: 90 },
                    { date: '08-02-2015', a: 87, b: 90 },
                    { date: '08-03-2015', a: 95, b: 90 },
                    { date: '08-04-2015', a: 86, b: 90 },
                    { date: '08-05-2015', a: 43, b: 90 },
                    { date: '08-06-2015', a: 25, b: 90 },
                    { date: '08-07-2015', a: 0, b: 90 },

        ]
```

Comment: What does the source array look like?

Comment: What kind of plugin do you use to make the line chart and how the array should look like?

Comment: I am using morris.js plugin, and the array should look like this, with all days of current month, where at least one record was made:

data: [
         { date: '07-31-2015', a: 6, b: 90, c:55, d:65 },
         { date: '08-01-2015', a: 0, b: 90, c:55, d:65  },
         { date: '08-02-2015', a: 87, b: 90, c:55, d:65  }]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could trigger with jQuery, for example, an AJAX GET (or POST...) request (`$.get()`) to the server (Laravel) that fetches data from the DB, stores it in the desidered array structure and returns it to the client; then you can instantiate and populate the chart directly from the `$.get()` callback function.
In PHP you can build the array as usual, for example within a `foreach` cycle, than return it to the client at the end of the script.

Something like this:

CLIENT SIDE (JavaScript)

```
$(function(){
    $.get("myPHPresource",{},function(AJAXdata){
        new Morris.Line({
            [...]
            data: AJAXdata,
            [...]
        });
    });
});
```

SERVER SIDE (php file pointed by myPHPresource)

```
<?php
$ret=array();
$data=fetch_DB_data();
foreach($data as $d){
    $current_data=array();
    //the following three lines are hypothetical and depend on how data is returned from your fetch_DB_data() function
    $current_data["date"]=$d["date"];
    $current_data["a"]=$d["a"];
    $current_data["b"]=$d["b"];
    $ret[]=$current_data;
}
exit($ret);
?>
```

To show only the days with at least one record, you could operate either at the database query level (probably better: using `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` where `count(records)>0`) or at PHP level: inside the `foreach` you can avoid pushing `$current_data` to `$ret` if the record count is `<=0`.